# Shell Scripting: Calling mailx in a loop

Tags: shell, scripting, mailx

I am trying to write a script using which I need to send multiple emails with a file as attachment per email. This is because of mail attachment size limitations.

I have zip files in a directory and they are file01.zip, file02.zip etc. and there will be about 4-5 of these files.

```
-- File count is normally passed in
numFiles=5
fileCounter=1
datestr="`date +"%m/%d/%Y"`"

while [ $fileCounter -le $numFiles ]
do
    SUBJECT_LINE="Weekly files ($fileCounter of $numFiles) - $datestr"

    echo "[`date`] E-mailing file ($fileCounter of $numFiles) ... "
    ZIPFILE="file0$fileCounter.zip"
    echo $ZIPFILE
    ls -ltr $ZIPFILE
    mailx -a "$ZIPFILE" \
          -r no-reply@host.com \
          -s "$SUBJECT_LINE" \
          $TO_LIST < /dev/null
    echo "[`date`] Done"
    fileCounter=$(( $fileCounter + 1 ))
done
```

I am trying to call mailx in a loop as you can see. I tried the following as well

```
for file in file0*.zip
do
...


done
```

I am able to see the ZIPFILE names when I print them out using echo but the mailx command in the loop returns the following although the files are there:

```
No such file or directory
```

I can run the same mailx command from console and have the e-mail sent out. I can also send one e-mail without a loop, but doing so inside a loop seems to cause an issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Amar

What I'm seeing is that you only are declaring the name of the file without adding the full path, try it using the full path of the files as shell script doesn't recognize where's the file(s) located.

to your variablare `ZIPFILE` add full path like this `ZIPFILE="THIS/IS/THE/FILES/PATH/file0${fileCounter}.zip"`

Comment: I did add the full path in my testing before I posted this and that did not work either. I tried that and a line before the code snippet above for a "cd to the directory that has the files". Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

I likely had one or more characters not visible to the eye in the file name ($ZIPFILE) being passed in as attachment to mailx. I typed parts of the script today again while troubleshooting and that fixed the issue. But the script above is good.